# Print last digit of time statement

Tags: python, time

Given this code:

```
from datetime import datetime

Time = datetime.now()

print(Time)
```

How could I print just the last digit? eg.

> 2013-02-08 15:13:32.150263 prints 3
>   2013-02-08 15:17:40.759672 prints 2

Comment: Why do you want this?  It seems like there's probably a better way to do whatever it is you're attempting :)

Comment: I need to present a reaction time to my participants, but only the last digit of the microsecond. Why is a whole big question. Since today is my first day with python, I was getting frustrated at the first hurdle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`print str(Time)[-1]` would do the trick...

Comment: I am writing an experiment. This gets me a little closer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
print str(Time)[-1:]
```

Comment: Why the slice? ... *padding with a few more characters so SO will think this is a valid comment ...*

Comment: @mgilson: right. technically, you don't need the slice here. just typed the answer as fast as I could. :-)